# Spring security ComponentScan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application which uses role authorization with spring security. The security setup and configuration including custom filters is stored in a `common` module inside a single package. To use other packages from the `common` module in my app, I need to use `@ComponentScan` and specify the packages to scan, but if don't include the security package it seems like Spring still registers it and implements the security configuration and filters. Why is that?
Project structure:

```
module
    |common
    |   |src/main/java
    |   |   |com.company.product.common
    |   |   |   |redis
    |   |   |   |es
    |   |   |   |spring (the security configuration)
    |main_module
    |   |src/main/java
    |   |   |com.company.product.service
    |   |   |   |ServiceMainApp.java
```

Conifguration classes:

```
package com.company.product.common.spring.configuration;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityFilter securityFilter;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.addFilterAfter(securityFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).csrf().disable();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class MethodSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${service.security.enabled:true}")
    private boolean securityEnabled;

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityMetadataSource customMethodSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return securityEnabled ? new SecuredAnnotationSecurityMetadataSource() : null;
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.product.service", "com.company.product.common.redis"})
@EnableCaching
public class ServiceMainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceMainApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the package structure of the common module, and the package structure of the main class in the consuming app?

Comment: @AndrewS,
common (`spring` has the security config):
`com.company.portal.common.spring`
`com.company.portal.common.redis`
`com.company.portal.common.es`
 
main: `com.company.portal.customer`

Comment: @Robert did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on your main class, and your package structure should look something like this.

```
src/main/java/
    -> Main
        -> securitypackage
        -> all other packages
```

If this is the case, you are automatically adding the following annotations to your main.

- `@EnableAutoConfiguration`: enable Spring Boot’s auto-configuration mechanism
- `@ComponentScan`: enable `@Component` scan on the package where the application is located
- `@Configuration`: allow to register extra beans in the context or import additional configuration classes

As you can see, with this one annotation, you are really adding three annotations in one, in which `@ComponetScan` is included. You can find a lot more on the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

**Update**

If you need to exclude packages from your component scan, you can use the `excludeFilters` option. For example, if you want to exclude everything inside the `es` and `spring` packages, you could do the follow.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.company.product.service", "com.company.product.common.redis"},
        excludeFilters = {
             @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.company.product.common.spring.*"),
             @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.company.product.common.es.*")})
```

If `@Filter` doesn't work try using `@Component.Filter` instead. Hope it works.

Comment: I added the project structure. The problem is that when I specify the `@ComponentScan({"com.company.product.service"})` and run the app, I get an error saying, that I am missing the redis components, but when I add `@ComponentScan({"com.company.product.service", "com.company.product.common.redis"})`, I don't get the error, so that means Spring doesn't automatically scan everything in common package.

Comment: The problem with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, is that it will only scan packages that are inside it's package. So, the ones that are levels above won't be scanned. If you want it to scan everything using `@SpringBootApplication`, the main class has to be on the upper level, and everything down from there. Like the structure example I posted. This behaviour is the same as the default behaviour of `@ComponentScan` if you don't set any parameter.

Comment: But my problem is actually that it implements the security setup and configuration that is in `com.company.product.common.spring`, even though I don't specify to scan it.

Comment: Then, remove the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation and instead add `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, `@Configuration` and leave the `@ComponentScan` as you have it.

Comment: But then why didn't it scan `com.company.product.common.redis`, but did scan `com.company.product.common.spring`, when I added `@ComponentScan({"com.company.product.service"})`?

Comment: Are you using `@EnableWebSecurity` on your security configuration? I believe this annotation automatically adds itself as Spring configuration without the need to be scanned. This is a thought though, trying to find some info on it.

Comment: None of the proposals worked. It seems like Spring still adds the beans even though I don't specify the package to scan (also removed `@SpringBootApplication`). But it turns out that it also created all the beans in the `common.es` package, so it is not Spring Security related.

Comment: Do you mind adding the code for your configuration files as well as your main class? I would like to have look at them.

Comment: Added the code to the question description. But it looks like the security `spring` package is not the problem, because Spring also creates generates beans from the `es` package. The question now would be how to tell Spring not to look in all the packages in `common`.

Comment: Very odd. Seems like Spring still scans and registers the beans inside the `es` and `spring` packages, but excluding `redis` does work.

Comment: Could you share your project in GitHub? O share some of the files that inside those two packages? In Tempe case of Spring Security, I believe that annotation auto configure itself, but I wanna see what else is in it.

Comment: It would be easier to create a mock project, because there is a lot to change because of company confidentiality. I might do it some time soon. If I do, I'll let you know.