# Spring Security 404 error after log in standard form

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a problem with my simple Spring Security app. After I logged in, 404 error page opens instead of my view (greet.jsp which contains only one header).

It seems to me, my controller doesn't handle requests, but I dont know why. I've done this before without Spring Security and it worked. But when I added Security, it doesn't work anymore.

Added dependencies: Spring Web MVC, Spring Security Wev/Config, javax-servlet-api.

My Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("security.config")
@EnableWebMvc
public class SpringConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

My Security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        User.UserBuilder userBuilder = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder();

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(userBuilder.username("Matt").password("Matt").roles("Programmer"));
    }
}
```

DispatcherServletInitializer:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
```

SecurityInitializer:

```
public class SecurityInitializer
        extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String getInfoForAllStaff(){
        return "greet";
    }
}
```

jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greet</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h2>Hello!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

After this, 404 error page

[image: Login page]

Please, someone tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since i can't add comments yet I have to write it as an answer.
I've had similar problem dealing with spring security, in my case it was because of `@ComponentScan` annotation (explained in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161479/14250809)) , fixing it solved my problem, perhaps it will also solve your.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It was a mistake in package name